# JS библиотека для построения гистограмм

Tags: javascript

Подскажите js-библиотеки для построения/отрисовки гистограмм

Answer (score 1):

Их очень много...

- [TufteGraph](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/)
- [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/)
- [PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/)
- [Sencha Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/#sample-4)
- [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)
- [JS Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/)
- [Style Chart](http://chart.inetsoft.com/)
- [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples?hl=ru)

Comment: [Visualization libraries](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Visualization-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

я использовал только [jQuery Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) он поддреживает [разные типы графиков](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html), в том чиcле и гистограммы.

- отличная скорость работы
- простота использования
- гибкие настройки

кстате, ХэшКод тоже использует эту библиотеку для построения графика репутации

- [Как создать интерактивный график используя CSS3 и jQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150150/)

а так [[@Iron](/users/26/iron)](/users/26/iron) прав, их огромное кол-во:

- [Visualization libraries](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Visualization-libraries)
- [20 Fresh JavaScript Data Visualization Libraries](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-fresh-javascript-data-visualization-libraries/)

Comment: я посмотрела список, мне больше JSChart Bar подходит..только там код на странице..а чтобы он работал нужно что-то скачать?

Comment: Ну да, саму библиотеку